# Three dots instead of \ldots

Tags: programming

When writing the TeX-codes we often use the 6-symbols \ldots command. It should be more comfortable to type merely three dots ... instead. Just the same as for TeX-parsing the minus symbols - or -- or ---. So I wonder, is it possible reprogram internal TeX understanding the triple ... into the \ldots-command. Of course the single/double dots . and .. should be of the standard meaning.

Comment: `\dots` is just five. ;-)

Comment: Redefining dots will have nasty effects (specially on tikz, pgffor and probably other packages).

Comment: If it is about saving keystrokes, you can `\let\dd=\ldots`

Comment: @JLDiaz: Save even another keystroke, since the `=` is optional (see [`\let\foo\bar` vs `\let\foo=\bar`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141166/5764)): `\let\dd\ldots`

Comment: unless you're using a font that has an ellipsis symbol the ligaturing mechanism (used for `--` and `---`) won't work.  and even if that symbol *is* in the font, it's usually "narrower" (not as much space between the dots) than ideal for dots in math.

Comment: It'a a pitty. Simple dots ... seems to be the only preferable solution. Otherwise the game is not worth the candle. What about \...  ?

Comment: @maximav `\...` would only be a valid macro name if the catcode of `.` were changed, which probably would have undesirable side effects. Just stick with `\dots`.

Comment: \def\...{\ldots} works for my LaTeX. But where reefs may come from?

Comment: @maximav `\def\...` redefines the macro `\.` not the macro `\...` (so breaks any letter with a dot accent)

Comment: Sounds nice. But why A\ldots and A\... gives exactly the same positioning the dots after A? Except for a space after the dots themselves.

Comment: I've checked again and \def\...{\ldots\ignorespaces} works like a usual correct command. Now, is it possible to know an internal definition of \. command (dot above a symbol)? Something like \mathchar"17D which makes a prime in math-mode. If such an independent definition of \. exists I could seems correct my def \... including standard action of \. By the way, its a pity that it is not possible to redefine \def. whilst we may do this for \def~

Comment: Some tex editors have built-in features to replace triple dots by \ldots automatically.

Answer (score 14):

It is pointless to define `\def\...`:  if you want to redefine `\.` just use `\renewcommand\.{\ldots}` or some such. (so the use is just two characters `\.`) As noted in comments this will break any use of the dot accent.  Using an alternative form for dot accent isn't really possible as `inputenc` uses `\.` in its definition of accented characters, so if you want to redefine `\.` without breaking the accent you would have to change the encoding definition for every encoding that includes characters with that accent.

By far the best course is to use the existing `\ldots` or `\dots` commands, or use  utf8 encoding and use the ellipsis character `…` (U+2026 ) directly.