# How to rename an existing command?

Tags: macros

I would like to know if renaming a command is possible in LaTeX.
For instance, could I change the `\section` by `\sec` ?

I read that some people used something called "alias".

Comment: `\let\sec\section` and then use `\sec`. That way you don't loose `\section` you just copy its definition to `\sec`.

Comment: The most natural way is `\newcommand{\sec}{\section}`. But the best way is *not* doing it. Using an alias for a command might confuse your editor (code folding features, for instance).

Answer (score 20):

There are a number of ways, depending on what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\let\TextBF\textbf% Copy definition of \textbf into \TextBF

\textbf{textbf}\par
\TextBF{TextBF}

\let\textbf\texttt% Change original \textbf to now be equivalent to \texttt

\textbf{textbf}\par
\TextBF{TextBF}% \TextBF remains unchanged

\hrulefill

\newcommand{\TextIT}{\textit}% \TextIT will be replaced with \textit

\textit{textit}\par
\TextIT{TextIT}

\let\textit\texttt% Change original \textit to now be equivalent to \texttt

\textit{textit}\par
\TextIT{TextIT}% \TextIT changes with \textit

\end{document}
```

- `\let<csnameA><csnameB>` makes a copy of the definition of `<csnameB>` and places it into `<csnameA>` (like a regular copy-and-paste). It has the advantage that you can now redefine `<csnameB>` without affecting the copy you just made (`<csnameA>`).
- `\newcommand{<csnameA>}{<csnameB>}` merely points `<csnameA>` to `<csnameB>`. To that end, updates to `<csnameB>` will still be reflected in `<csnameA>`.

Related questions:

- [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)
- [`\let\foo\bar` *vs* `\let\foo=\bar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141166/5764)

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you want to copy (i.e. if the original command is modified the new command keeps the old value), you can use:

```
\NewCommandCopy\newMacro\oldMacro
\RenewCommandCopy\newMacro\oldMacro
\DeclareCommandCopy\newMacro\oldMacro
```

that is more robust on commands created via `\NewDocumentCommand` for instance.

Comment: Note that copying a command doesn't incorporate any changes that may be implemented after the definition.

Comment: @Werner good point, edited

Comment: This is the recommended way as of 2023.