# How to rename the comment or verbatim environment?

Tags: errors, verbatim, comments, text-manipulation, technical-environment

Based on the question [How to rename or "copy" a latex environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286084/how-to-rename-or-copy-a-latex-environment) I am tried to rename the `comment` environment to `myenvironment`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{comment}

\makeatletter

% \newenvironment{myenvironment}{\comment}{\endcomment}

\let\myenvironment\comment
\let\endmyenvironment\endcomment

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    This is normal text.

\begin{myenvironment}

         How to make this environment be \bfseries{verbatim}?

\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

However it do the error:

```
Excluding 'comment' comment.)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ./test2.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./test2.tex
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start to read some documentation. The one from  comment explictly describes how to create new comment like environments.

Comment: Sorry, I just did it I wrote a wrong question.

Comment: The comment package allows I create new environment with `\excludecomment{myenvironment}`, and the verbatim accepted doing `\let\myotherenvironment\verbatim` to be renamed correctly.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question code was badly tested:

1. The `comment` environment can be "renamed" by creating new environment version with its macro `\excludecomment{myenvironment}`
2. The `verbatim` environment accepted correctly to be renamed with `\let\myotherenvironment\verbatim` and `\let\endmyotherenvironment\endverbatim`:

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{comment}

% How to rename an existing command?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193379/how-to-rename-an-existing-command
\newcommand{\supertiny}{\fontsize{2pt}{2.5pt}\selectfont}

\excludecomment{myenvironment}
\newenvironment{myotherenvironment}{\verbatim\supertiny}{\normalfont\endverbatim}

\begin{document}
     This is normal text.

\begin{myenvironment}
     How to make this environment be a comment?
\end{myenvironment}

\begin{myotherenvironment}
     How to make this environment be {\bfseries verbatim}?
\end{myotherenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a hint: `\bfseries` has no argument.