# What's the meaning of \@tempskipa?

Tags: registers

Looking at the source code I could not figure out what the command does, I know it is a "skip" (I admit I'm unaware about how skips work), since it is defined by

```
\newskip\@tempskipa
```

as on [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) file, but in the sectioning commands is used everywhere without a precise setting.

Comment: `\@tempskipa` is a skip register which is temporarily used by many macros for internal stuff. E.g., a macro could use `\@tempskipa` to do some calculations and another macro could reuse it. LaTeX was written when there weren't too many registers available in TeX and therefore it had to be economical in the usage of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name says, it's a temporary (or scratch) skip register. LaTeX defines two of these, `\@tempskipa` and `\@tempskipb`. Skip registers are length registers that may contain glue (either stretch or shrink).

LaTeX defines these temporary skip to be used in all kinds of calculations and conditionals. Specifically in `\@startsection` (in [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)), this is what it looks like:

```
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
```

The line

```
\@tempskipa #4\relax
```

is actually an assignment of the fourth argument in `\@startsection` to `\@tempskipa`, since the "assignment operator" `=` is optional. Subsequently

```
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
```

`\@tempskipa` is checked against `\z@` (which is the length `0pt`). If `\@tempskipa` is less than `0pt` (in other words, negative), it's changed to be positive via

```
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa
```

Remember, the assignment operator is optional, so the above statement changes `\@tempskipa`. Later on, `\@tempskipa` is added to the vertical space (if needed) via `\addvspace`.

---

Back to the fourth argument of `\@startsection`. See [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764). The fourth argument

```
\@startsection{<name>} % #1
  {<level>} % #2
  {<indent>} % #3
  {<beforeskip>} % #4
  {<afterskip>} % #5
  {<style>} % #6
```

denotes the `<beforeskip>` which is an "Absolute value = skip to leave above the heading. If negative, then paragraph indent of text following heading is suppressed." It should now make sense how `\@tempskipa` is used to condition on whether or not the skip value is negative, and then converted to positive again.

Comment: So, `\@tempskipa -\@tempskipa` is not zero. As a mathematician, I can not read like that.... lol

Comment: @Sigur: Indeed. [`tex.web`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web) is littered with a function/procedure call to `scan_optional_equals` which scans for spaces and an (optional) equal sign in assignments. Most notably, see Section **3.3.1  Implicit character tokens: `\let`** in [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic) where it mentions the `\let` syntax: `\let<control sequence><equals><token>`, yet `<equals>` is optional. Also see this discussion: [`\let\foo\bar` vs `\let\foo=\bar` (let with equals sign)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141166/5764).