# Is there any difference between `\let\A\B` and `\let\A=\B`?

Tags: macros

I've seen people writing things like

```
\let\original@somemacro=\somemacro
```

while I usually write

```
\let\original@somemacro\somemacro
```

Is there any difference between them?

*(I believe this question must have been asked somewhere else on this site, but was not able to find it.)*

Comment: I add the = for clarity, since `\let\A=\B` is clear while `\let\A\B`  is slightly faster.

Comment: Duplicate of [tex core - \let\foo\bar vs \let\foo=\bar (let with equals sign) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141166/let-foo-bar-vs-let-foo-bar-let-with-equals-sign) (flagging for crosslinking purpose only.) (searching for that one is unexpectedly easy this time, first result of "site:tex.stackexchange.com let equal sign" )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can be pretty safe doing things explicitly because you know the values of the components in advance, but in code (i.e., macros) where you may not know what the user may wish to assign, you can get burned if you do not use the `=` as part of the assignment.  Therefore, it is a good habit to use it.

Consider this case that misbehaves without the `=` in the `\let` assignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\doit#1{\let\X#1}

\doit{=} what?

\X oops
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare it to the output, when the `=` is added to the `\let` syntax.  Ah, much more expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\doit#1{\let\X=#1}

\doit{=} what?

\X much better
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another case to highlight the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\deftok#1#2{\let#1= #2\empty}

\deftok\W{ }

*\W* success

\def\deftok#1#2{\let#1=#2\empty}

\deftok\W{ }

*\W* fail

\def\deftok#1#2{\let#1 #2\empty}

\deftok\W{ }

*\W* fail
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example, not only is the `=` imperative, but so is the space following the `=`, if you wish to do assignments of spaces.  The syntax also allows `\deftok\W{}` to assign `\empty` to `\W`.

So in summary, spaces and `=` tokens can be problematic assignments with `\let` and care must be exercised.  I learned this lesson the hard way in V1.1 of my `tokcycle` package.  "Once burnt, twice learnt!"

Comment: So, is it a good habit to always add the `=`?

Comment: @Jinwen In general code, especially if to be used by others, absolutely yes.  In one-off assignments, used locally and discarded, you will know if the absence of the `=` is OK.

Comment: @Jinwen In case you wish to be able to assign the meaning of space-token, too, then it is a good habit to add `= `, i.e., `=<space>`, because with `\let`-assignments after `=`  one <optional space> is discarded.

Answer (score 11):

The previous answer shows why `=` is usable to use it in `\let` syntax. Another argument is "more clarity".

I show different view, i.e. a case where usage of `=` is somewhat impractical in `\let` syntax: when the second token of `\let` is constructed by `\csname...\endcsname`. The following example is wrong:

```
\let\foo = \csname bar\endcsname
```

because `\let` scans its parameters without expansion: the example above does `\let\foo=\csname` and the `bar\endcsname` follows with the error when `\endcsname` is processed. So, we must use the `\expandafter` chain:

```
\expandafter\let \expandafter\foo \expandafter=\csname bar\endcsname
```

We can spare one `\expandafter` if we do not use `=` here:

```
\expandafter\let \expandafter\foo \csname bar\endcsame
```

If both tokens scanned by `\let` must be constructed by `\csname...\endcsname` pair then we can use another trick with "`\expandafter` started inside `\csname...\endcsname` pair":

```
\expandafter\let \csname foo\expandafter\endcsname \csname bar\endcsname
```

In old macros, the `=` from `\let` syntax was not used in macro bodies because it spares one token in the TeX memory. But this is irrelevant today.

Comment: This is why `expl3` allows `\cs_set_eq:NN \foo \bar`, `\cs_set_eq:Nc \foo {bar}`, `\cs_set_eq:cN {foo} \bar` and `\cs_set_eq:cc {foo} {bar}`

Comment: We are using TeX primitive constructs and we have no problems. There are few basic and well known "cubes from the kit" at TeX primitive level. We need not to know plenty another control sequences from expl3.